# Races based on zodiac signs: what would Libra be?

Tags: biology, fantasy-races, races

I am right now in the middle of designing a race for my world, but I have run into a problem. You see, the form a member of this race has depends on when they are born in the horoscope. I have a race for all of the signs but Libra:

- Capricorn: Goat Race
- Aquarius: Water Spirit
- Pisces: People Of Mer  (Multiple possible races)
- Aries: Sheep/Ram Race
- Taurus: Taurian Race/centaur, cattaur, cowtaur etc
- Gemini: Dual Personalities
- Cancer: Natural Biological Body Armor
- Leo: Cat-kin (Multiple possible races)
- Virgo: Breath Taking Beauty/Always Female/Dryad
- Libra: ???
- Scorpio: Scorpion Drider (Drider=Arachnid centaur)
- Sagittarius: Wood Elf

What form could my species take if they were a Libra? It needs to be a race that either fits with the word "Libra", or can be connected with the scales symbol.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. I can sympathize with your difficulty brainstorming a critter that can be associated with Libra. However brainstorming is too open ended and opinion based to make for a good question for this site.

Comment: ya but where else do i turn and i need the opinion of people cause i am clueless where other people will have a opinion i can use

Comment: Ares and Capricorn sound very similar. . . .

Comment: one is very woolly other is not

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b9/36/66/b93666b6bd553a807d361d219dcd92c7.jpg goat

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/474x/4d/3c/d1/4d3cd1308a28170082d92e22b23148e6.jpg sheep

Comment: I'm not sure "dual personalities" really fits with the others. I suspect that real-life individuals with DID (dissociative identity disorder) would object to being classified as a "race" or "species", much like real-life individuals with dwarfism would. Unfortunately, I can't suggest anything better.

Comment: @AlexandriaCourvoisier I agree with Sphennings, it's not the best place to look purely for ideas. You should have a way to measure what would be the best answer. Lemme look, I think I had a post about possible resources... [Here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources)! You might find both thoughts and forums for thought to develop your zodiac ideas.

Comment: @F1Krazy it is more real than did meaning 2 brains in 1 head smaler than normal but still each brin controlls certain aspects one is more creative but no number sence the other is more mathmaticly inclined but no creativity ect....

Comment: and each has their own personality and soul

Comment: @AlexandriaCourvoisier Maybe two heads with one brain each, would be simpler than one head with two brains.

Comment: I really think cancer should be crab people.  Possibly crabataurs.  And crabby too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Justice is Blind**

[image]

(1) Humans with no eyes but very good at making impartial decisions. They make good judges.

(2) Humans with no eyes but other senses enhanced.

(3) Echolocating bat people.

[image]

Comment: The bat people would be akin to Nemesis and the Furies from Greek mythology. They were the hands of punishment for the gods.

Comment: i think ill use the human with no eyes idea thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexandriaCourvoisier No problemo my friend. Make sure to give them a superpower though, or no one will want to play as a Libra.

Comment: @AlexandriaCourvoisier Maybe their superpower is cooperation?

Comment: i am thinking sence magic so bonous for mages

Comment: @AlexandriaCourvoisier if this is your favourite answer then please wait 24 hours and then click the green tick to indicate it.

Answer (score 12):

## Mechanical Humanoid

Out of all signs of the zodiac, Libra is the only one represented by a mechanism, that being the scales. Therefore, a fitting idea for your species could be a mechanical humanoid, powered and controlled by chains and levers like an overcomplicated set of scales

Comment: Oooh! Good thinking!

Comment: Or maybe Libra is just a boring old robot -- but there is no advanced technology in this world, so they are just seen as "clanky metal people".

Answer (score 2):

## Balance

The scales are all about balance, so let's make it so.  Make them Druids who harmonize the forces of nature so that multiple species can exist under the most beneficial conditions.  Allow them to act similarly for humans, like "Jedi for judgment" from some of the Star Wars stories: rather than ordering about men with clubs and cells, they propose inspired solutions that allow people or civilizations voluntarily to find peace with each other.  Their culture is one of harmony - which is often to say of staying out of each others' way, which is one reason why you find them so much in the wilderness; but they also move among all the other Forms, bringing wisdom and collaboration, and are also known for building great institutions of learning, philosophy and reasoned debate.

Incidentally, I think there may be better ways to describe these creatures than "races".  That usage seems dated, recalling the days of H.P. Lovecraft, where it seemed believable to an audience that a small diverged group of people would turn into degenerate fish-creatures.  Great stories, to be sure, but writing a new story that way you'd be fighting other assumptions and associations.  This is particularly true in this situation, where these Forms seem to depend on the time of birth, and don't breed true -- at least, not unless some folks are very disciplined in following the rhythm method, and even then there could be slip-ups.  I'm favoring "Forms" here in a Platonic sense; you could say Archetypes, Resonances, Modes...  Or you could go accurately with the technical "Phenotype" ([polyphenism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphenism)), or make it less awkward by altering it to "phene".  The term "Caste" in reference to insects is usable.